# Select dataframe columns based on conditions

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

**Input DataFrame :**

```
    a   b  c    d   e    f    g       j   k  l    m    n    o    p    q   r      s  t
2  33  17  0  418  -5  -81  NaN   14336  81  1  462  -24  NaN   81    1   462  -24 NaN  
5  33  17  0  415  -5  -116 NaN   14336  81  0  487   -5  116   81    1   462  -24 NaN 
7  33  17  0  413  -5  -116 NaN   14336  81  1  462  -24  NaN   81    1   462  -24 -111
```

Check the value of column `c` if it's equal to `0`: insert the values of `d` `e` `f` into `x1` `x2` `x3`
Check the value of column `l` if it's equal to `0`: insert the values of `m` `n` `o` into `y1` `y2` `y3`

if he value of column `l` is equal to `1` : 
check columns `o` and `t` : the first that contains a value, insert `m` `n` `o`, or `r` `s` `t` into columns `z1` `z2` `z3`

**Output DataFrame:**

```
    x1  x2    x3    y1    y2    y3    z1   z2    z3
2  418  -5   -81   NaN   NaN   NaN   462  -24   NaN
5  415  -5  -116   487    -5   116   462  -24   NaN
7  413  -5   -81   NaN   NaN   NaN   462  -24  -111
```

Comment: Is there a particular part of the problem where you got stuck?

Comment: Can you explain more `the first that contains a value` ?

Comment: How working my solution? It is what you want?

Answer (score 0):

I believe need [`where`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.where.html) for filter by condition with [`concat`](http://pands.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html) for join all `DataFrame`s together and [`combine_first`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.combine_first.html) for replace `NaN`s by another `DataFrame`:

```
df1 = df[['d','e','f']].where(df['c'].eq(0))
df1.columns = ['x1','x2','x3']

df2 = df[['m','n','o']].where(df['l'].eq(0))
df2.columns = ['y1','y2','y3']

df31 = df[['m','n','o']].where(df['l'].eq(1) & df['o'].notnull())
df31.columns = ['z1','z2','z3']

df32 = df[['r','s','t']].where(df['l'].eq(1) & df['t'].notnull())
df32.columns = ['z1','z2','z3']

df = pd.concat([df1, df2, df31.combine_first(df32)], axis=1)
print (df)
    x1  x2   x3     y1   y2     y3     z1    z2     z3
2  418  -5  -81    NaN  NaN    NaN    NaN   NaN    NaN
5  415  -5 -116  487.0 -5.0  116.0    NaN   NaN    NaN
7  413  -5 -116    NaN  NaN    NaN  462.0 -24.0 -111.0
```

Comment: the answer differs from the desired output as the question is not clear.